# How to create generic method which I used an instance of generic type T.class?

Tags: java, generics

I Have a dozer mapping  could convert class to class  And I want to have general methode with type that I can just  call it with Instance that I would 
for example UserDto to User

```
User user = ConvertToUsingDozerMapping.convertToUsingDozerMapping(userDto)
for example AddressDto to Address
User user = ConvertToUsingDozerMapping.convertToUsingDozerMapping(addressDto)

public class ConvertToUsingDozerMapping<I,O> {

    @Autowired
    private DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean dozerBean;

    public I convertToUsingDozerMapping(O o)  {

        Mapper mapper = null;
        mapper = (Mapper) dozerBean.getObject();
        I i=  mapper.map(o, I.class);// doesn't compile
        return i;

    }

}
```

Comment: Aside from the fact you can't do that with generics, where is T defined?

Comment: Try this: https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics

Comment: Not only can you not do this, you aren't specifying a generic type here, and this is not a static method: `ConvertToUsingDozerMapping.convertToUsingDozerMapping`

Comment: I think it can be done, I've editted the answer, hope that helps.

Comment: I mean I.class not T.class

Answer (score -1):

Do not use T.class inside the generic class/method. Instead extract the argument to the invoker that does not use generics adding a Class clazz argument.

---

About creating generic methods, use this scheme:

```
public <I, O> I convertToUsingDozerMapping(O o)  {
   ...
}
```

**EDIT**:

Originally the question was answering more on how to make a generic method. I didn't focused on the mapper.map issue.

Indeed I saw the T.class and assumed directly that the question was issuing to convert with mapper.map into type I, that's why I added I.class, but as mentioned in the comments this does not work.

**Now, focusing on the T.class issue:**

I would solve it by getting out the T.class or I.class issue to outside the generic method and/or even outside the generic class if necesary by creating a new clazz argument, with the same type of mapper.map, from where you can use/specify manually which type to use (check the bottom example). After that you can pass directly the clazz argument to the mapper.map, without .class and without problems.

Check this if it works for you (a third T type can be used, or remove it and use only I and O):

```
public <I, O, T> I convertToUsingDozerMapping(O o, Class<? extends T> clazz)  {
   ...
   I i = mapper.map(o, clazz);
   ...
}
```

I add also a generic basic java compiler-test example. You can use it also as test-field for newer tests, it's simple but the map method arguments should be the same types as mapper.map:

```
class TestG {

    public static <I, O, T> I map(O o, Class<? extends T> clazz) {
        System.out.println("map dummy implementation");
        return null; // this is only a check function, no implementation done
    }

    public <I, O, T> I convertToUsingDozerMapping(O o, Class<? extends T> clazz) {
        I i = map(o, clazz);
        return i;
    }

    public void testme() {

        System.out.println("----- CONVERT TEST/ -----");

        String s = "";
        Integer i = 1;
        String r = convertToUsingDozerMapping(i, String.class);

        System.out.println("----- /CONVERT TEST -----");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestG t = new TestG();
        t.testme();
    }

}
```

Comment: The question was redacted in other way when I answered, this is how to create a generic method, instead of a generic class, or, if needed within a generic class...

Comment: it does not work  the issue is I.class  not T.class just a mistake

Comment: did you reviewed the TestG class? I.class does not work, indeed, but you can extract the generic Class<? extends T> clazz to the outside invoker, who instead can do ClassName.class which should work for any class.

Comment: As I commented I directly assumed that you T.class was a mistake so I added I.class, but that indeed didn't work as well, that's why I added the TestG example.
I.class does not work, but clazz argument, of type Class<? extends T> does work.

Comment: Yes it work  for any class but how I can use it for multiple classe in the same class how I can Call it. right now I use it like THat    public class UserServiceImpl extends ConvertToUsingDozerMapping<User, UserDto> but supose If want to use i this converter for an other class Like address in the same class  UserServiceImpl  ....  you can't extends two class

Answer (score -1):

It work for me like that

public class ConvertToUsingDozerMapping {

```
@Autowired
private DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean dozerBean;   
public I convertToUsingDozerMapping(O o, Class<? extends I> clazz) throws Exception  {

    Mapper mapper = null;
    mapper = (Mapper) dozerBean.getObject();
    I i=    mapper.map(o, clazz);
    return i;

}
```

}

when I want to use it I need to heritate the class
 public class SignUpServiceImpl extends ConvertToUsingDozerMapping

But Like that I can do it just for User in all  my class

I need to do use it for many object in the same class 
Like that   : 
ConvertToUsingDozerMapping convertUserDtoToUser = new ConvertToUsingDozerMapping();

ConvertToUsingDozerMapping convertAddressDtoToAddress = new ConvertToUsingDozerMapping();

but when I do that it does not working I have exception  nullpointerException att Mapper Idont know why  ?